# 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'HitTest' and no accessible extension method 'HitTest'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello and Good Night.

I already looked for all the solutions on Google, including putting "using UnityEngine.UI;", I tried to leave only "Image" and "Texture" instead of "GUITexture or UI.Image" and this causes even more errors, I don't know what else to do. I would be grateful for the help. Thank you very much.

code:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class GUIItemButton : GUIItem
{
    public Sprite _texNormalState;
    public Sprite _texSelectedState;
    public Sprite _texHoverState;
    public Sprite  _texDisabledState;
    public bool _HighLiteOnHover = false;
   
    bool mbButtonHover = false;
    bool mbMouseClicked = false;
    bool mbDisabled = false;
    bool mbRespondsToInput = true;
       
    public delegate void clickCallBack();
    public clickCallBack _CallBack = null;
    Vector3 mViewRectPosOffset = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    Camera mCamera = null;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Button start");
        meGUIItemType = eGUI_ITEM_TYPE.Button;
        if(mCamera == null)
        {
            mCamera = Camera.main;
            mViewRectPosOffset = new Vector3(mCamera.rect.x*Screen.width,mCamera.rect.y*Screen.height,0);
        }
    }
   
    public void setCamera(Camera pCam)
    {
        mCamera = pCam;
        mViewRectPosOffset = new Vector3(mCamera.rect.x*Screen.width,mCamera.rect.y*Screen.height,0);
        //Debug.Log(mViewRectPosOffset+" name: "+gameObject.name);
    }
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        UpdateSizeWithViewPort();
       
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            HandleMouseClick();
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            HandleTouch();
        #else
            HandleMouseClick();
        #endif          
    }
   
    public void setRespondToInput(bool pResponds)
    {
        mbRespondsToInput = pResponds;
    }
   
   
    //HANDLE INPUT TOUCHES
    void HandleTouch()
    {
        if(mCamera == null || mbDisabled || !mbRespondsToInput)
            return;
       
        int touchCount = Input.touchCount;
        if(touchCount > 0)
        {
            if(mbDisabled)
                return;
           
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(touchCount-1);
           
            //IF THE BUTTON IS NOT YET CLICKED
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && mbMouseClicked == false)
            {
                if (GetComponent<Image>().HitTest(touch.position-(Vector2)mViewRectPosOffset, mCamera))
                {
                    //SET TO SELECTED TEXTURE
                    mbMouseClicked = true;
                    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texSelectedState;
                }
            }
           
            //IF THE BUTTON IS ALREADY CLICKED
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && mbMouseClicked == true)
            {
                mbMouseClicked = false;
                if (GetComponent<Image>().HitTest(touch.position-(Vector2)mViewRectPosOffset, mCamera))
                {
                    //PERFORM ACTION
                    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texNormalState;
                    if(_guiItemsManager !=null)
                        _guiItemsManager.OnSelectedEvent(this);  
                    else if(_CallBack != null)
                        _CallBack();
                }
            }  
           
           
            //HIGHLITE ON HOVER
            if (!mbButtonHover)
            {
                //CHECK IF MOUSE IS HOVERING ON BUTTON
                if (GetComponent<Image>().HitTest(touch.position-(Vector2)mViewRectPosOffset, mCamera))
                    mbButtonHover = true;
               
                if(mbButtonHover)
                {
                    //HIGHLITE BUTTON (SELECTED OR HOVER MODE)
                    if(mbMouseClicked)
                        GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texSelectedState;
                }
            }
           
            //IF MOUSE IS ALREADY HOVERING ON BUTTON
            else if (mbButtonHover)
            {
                if (!GetComponent<Image>().HitTest(touch.position-(Vector2)mViewRectPosOffset, mCamera))
                {
                    //HAPPENS ONLY IF MOUSE MOVES AWAY FROM BUTTON
                    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texNormalState;
                    mbButtonHover = false;
                }
            }
        }
       
        else
        {
            mbMouseClicked = false;
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texNormalState;
        }
    }
   
    void HandleMouseClick()
    {
        if(mCamera == null || mbDisabled || !mbRespondsToInput)
            return;
               
       
 
        //IF THE BUTTON IS NOT YET CLICKED
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && mbMouseClicked == false)
        {
           
            if (GetComponent<Image>().HitTest((Input.mousePosition-mViewRectPosOffset), mCamera))
            {
                //SET TO SELECTED TEXTURE
                //Debug.Log("Hit offset "+ (Input.mousePosition-mViewRectPosOffset));
                mbMouseClicked = true;
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texSelectedState;
            }
        }
       
        //IF THE BUTTON IS ALREADY CLICKED
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && mbMouseClicked == true)
        {
            mbMouseClicked = false;
            if (GetComponent<Image>().HitTest((Input.mousePosition-mViewRectPosOffset), mCamera))
            {
                //PERFORM ACTION
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texNormalState;
                if(_guiItemsManager !=null)
                    _guiItemsManager.OnSelectedEvent(this);  
                else if(_CallBack != null)
                    _CallBack();
            }
        }
       
        //HIGHLITE ON HOVER
        if (!mbButtonHover)
        {
            //CHECK IF MOUSE IS HOVERING ON BUTTON
            if (GetComponent<Image>().HitTest((Input.mousePosition-mViewRectPosOffset), mCamera))
                mbButtonHover = true;
           
            if(mbButtonHover)
            {
                //HIGHLITE BUTTON (SELECTED OR HOVER MODE)
                if(mbMouseClicked)
                    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texSelectedState;
                else if(_HighLiteOnHover)
                    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texHoverState;
            }
        }
       
        //IF MOUSE IS ALREADY HOVERING ON BUTTON
        else if (mbButtonHover)
        {
            if (!GetComponent<Image>().HitTest((Input.mousePosition-mViewRectPosOffset), mCamera))
            {
                //HAPPENS ONLY IF MOUSE MOVES AWAY FROM BUTTON
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texNormalState;
                mbButtonHover = false;
            }
        }
       }
   
    public void setDisabled(bool pState)
    {
        mbDisabled = pState;
        if(mbDisabled == true)
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texDisabledState;
        else
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = _texNormalState;
   
       
    }
   
    public bool getDisabled()
    {
        return mbDisabled;  
       
       
    }
}
```

Is there a problem?

Comment: Which Unity version are you using? There once was a [`GUIElement.HitTest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIElement.HitTest.html) which has been **deprecated** with `2019.3` .. you could switch to [`IPointerEnterHandler`/`IPointerExitHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html)

Comment: hey thank you for your help the project was working in unity 5 normal, right now i am using unity 2020 this issue only in this file above, can you please show how can i switch from HitTset ? thank you.